# Как с сайта на joomla отправить форму обратной связи?

Tags: php, javascript, post, joomla, email

Здравствуйте, подскажите как отправить заявку с форм обратной связи на емайл с сайта на joomla? 
пользовался всегда стандартным скриптом, js+php но теперь он js обрабатывает, отправляет все данные php а там уже ни чего не происходит, слышал что на joomla с этим проблемы.  Как решить это?
сайт: http://www.vorota-optima.ru/? 
firebug во вкладке ответ пусто.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте модуль JA Quick Contact и будет счастье https://www.joomlart.com/joomla/extensions/ja-quick-contact-module .

Если этот не понравится, [тут еще несколько десятков](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/?searchall=contact&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=30&filter%5Btype%5D=free&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1).

У Joomla нет проблем с отправкой писем, слухи не подтверждаются.

Comment: А без модулей можно это сделать? Просто запустить php из фронтенда?

Comment: Тут вот не рекомендуется https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/how-to-create-contact-form-from-scratch . Как вариант можно написать собственный модуль, или внедрить php в код шаблона - но стоит ли изобретать велосипед?

Comment: на доработке сайт с joomla года так 2012, я сомневаюсь, что новая версия того плагина которого вы рекомендуете нормально подключится к сайту, а обновлять полностью весь сайт нельзя ибо я боюсь что он не сохранит работу после обновления, а разбираться потом это ещё больший велосипед чем тот что я хочу сделать

Comment: Бэкап сайта в любом случае придется делать. Joomla скорее всего у вас версии 2.5, поставьте копию сайта на локалхосте, поставьте модуль, проверьте как работает, если все ОК, то тоже самое можно сделать с рабочей версией.

Comment: вот они проблемы, о которых я писал в начале, слухи подтверждаются:) на modx например, создал обработчик форм, подключил и все работает, никаких плясок с бубном вокруг расширений и добавлений полей